# Name of the Gamma function

Tags: mathematics, terminology, calculus

The Gamma function for positive arguments can be defined with the integral

$$ \Gamma(\alpha) = \int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}\,dx $$

The function $ x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x} $ is called the Gamma distribution when normalized.

How are the two names related?

- Did the Gamma function get this name and the $\Gamma$ symbol because the distribution was already called Gamma distribution?
- Or backwards, did the Gamma distribution get named from the Gamma function?
- Or were the two named together at the same time?
- Or are the two names independent and only accidentally the same letter, despite the apparent connection?

This question came up in a discussion about spelling mathematical terms, and while it's probably not actually relevant for that, I'm now curious about the origin of the names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Herbert A. David’s *First (?) Occurrence of Common Terms in Statistics and Probability* ([2010 revision](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://stat.iastate.edu/preprint/articles/2006-07.pdf)), “Gamma distribution” goes back to Paul G. Hoel, *A significance test for component analysis*, Annals of Mathematical Statistics **8** ([1937](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177732411)) 149–158. That’s much later than Legendre’s naming of the Gamma function (see Wikipedia).